# bug window.location.href + hash in Safari?

Tags: javascript, hash, safari

I have a script in my JavaScript file where I need to open a new file with a hash already set, something like:

```
function search(queryString){
    window.location.href = "dosome.php#" + queryString
}
```

because dosome.php is the page where I have all the scripts for the search...

I know it sounds like a hack, but I cant spend more time rebuilding everything. I'm just trying to fix it temporarily.

It works in Firefox and Chrome, but for some reason, it doesn't work in Safari-- it doesn't send the URL with the hash. Safari sends:

```
domain.com/dosome.php
```

instead of

```
domain.com/dosome.php#queryvalues
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean with *it doesn't send the url with hash* ? The hash is never sent to the server.

Comment: That's weird, Safari and Chrome use the same javascript engine? Which version of Safari are you on?

Comment: means that if i call directly the page as you see above, in Safari i will see domain.com/dosome.php with no hash values whereas Chrome is gonan be correctly domain.com/dosome.php#mavalues..

Comment: @rsplak: Safari and Chrome use the same rendering engine, but not the same javascript engine.

Answer (score 5):

If your server on `dosome.php` does some redirects, the hash is NOT retained, at least on Safari 4 and IE8. Chrome and Firefox work well.

In order to test this, try entering the URL `http://yourdomain.com/...dosome.php#...` in Safari's address bar and see if Safari keeps losing the `#`. (Test both with w/o `www`, even a simple www redirection loses the `#`.)

If this is the case, there is nothing you can do server-side because the `#...` is not sent to server; it's the client who is supposed to not lose it during navigation.

Comment: I write too fast, I write too wrong, but I usually read back and fix the mistakes. :)

Answer (score 1):

IS this done from the same page? Meaning, dosome.php?

Then try using location.hash,

```
location.hash = "#somestring";
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

The following code was failing on an iPhone 5 in Safari:

```
window.location.href = 'http://example.com/result#somehash'
```

Safari was redirecting to just http://example.com/result/

It was working correctly in Chrome on the same phone as well as on the desktop.

I noticed it was adding the forward slash to the end and wondered if just adding a forward slash between the hash would work.

It did!

I changed my code to this and it worked:

```
window.location.href = 'http://example.com/result/#somehash'
```

Notice the / before the hash.